# Groovy script to list Jenkins projects and TFS project path

Tags: groovy, jenkins, tfs

I am new to Jenkins, TFS and Groovy Script, but I have been researching and not found the exact way to do the following:
I would like to generate a list of all the Jenkins CI projects along with their TFS Project Path since the naming at my current company has been very inconsistent and I can't find which project in Jenkins CI correlates to which project in TFS without manually examining the project path in Jenkins.
I tried this, but it blows up since getProjectPath() isn't a method in Hudson.model.*

```
    import hudson.model.*

    jenkins = Hudson.instance

    for (item in jenkins.items)
    {
        println item.getFullDisplayName()
        println item.getProjectPath()
    }
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TFS](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Team+Foundation+Server+Plugin)'s configuration located under SCM (Source Control Management) configuration section. To access it at first you need to get SCM with [getScm()](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractProject.html#getScm()) method:

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.plugins.tfs.TeamFoundationServerScm

jenkins = Hudson.instance

for (item in jenkins.items)
{
    scm = item.getScm()

    if (scm instanceof TeamFoundationServerScm) {
        println item.getFullDisplayName()
        println scm.getProjectPath()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Vitalii Elenhaupt! That was exactly what I needed. it worked perfectly without any modification.